# How I'm I supposed to define "surname" in this code please?

Tags: python, flask, psql

I'm building flask application with psql. The code below is giving me nameError: 'surname' is not defined. I need help.

```
@app.route("/success", methods=["POST"])
def success():
            name = request.form.get("name")
            db.execute("INSERT INTO users (surname, firstname, email, username, pass_word) VALUES (:surname, :firstname, :email, :username, :pass_word)",
            {"surname":surname, "firstname":firstname, "email":email, "username":username, "pass_word":password})
            db.commit()
            return render_template("success.html", name=firstname)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error suggests, you haven't defined `surname`, or any of the other variables that will be substituted into your query.

You're defining a variable `name` which gets the value from the form, but this isn't being used. Assuming this is how you will be defining the other variables for the query, you will need to get these values from the form:

```
firstname = request.form.get('firstname')
surname = request.form.get('surname')

... etc
```